# Update JsonA Object Value if Same id with JsonB

Tags: javascript

```
var JsonA = [
   { "id":"2020-09-08", "y":0, "desc":"Sep 08" },
   { "id":"2020-09-09", "y":0, "desc":"Sep 09" },
   { "id":"2020-09-10", "y":0, "desc":"Sep 10" },
   { "id":"2020-09-11", "y":0, "desc":"Sep 11" },
   { "id":"2020-09-12", "y":0, "desc":"Sep 12" },
   { "id":"2020-09-13", "y":0, "desc":"Sep 13" },
   { "id":"2020-09-14", "y":0, "desc":"Sep 14" }
];

var JsonB= [
    {"id":"2020-09-11", "y":100 },
    {"id":"2020-09-14", "y":20  }
];

JsonA.map(item => {
    (item.id == JsonB.id) ? (item.y = JsonB.y) : ''; 
});

console.log("Modified Array", JsonA);
```

Hi I am new to javascript I wanted to replace the value of y of jsonA to value of y in Json B if id is the same of jsonA and JsonB however my code is not changing anything in json A . Thanks in advance for help. Currently I am getting wrong result where y are all 0 still even got same id with json B
expected output is

```
[
   { "id":"2020-09-08", "y":0,   "desc":"Sep 08" },
   { "id":"2020-09-09", "y":0,   "desc":"Sep 09" },
   { "id":"2020-09-10", "y":0,   "desc":"Sep 10" },
   { "id":"2020-09-11", "y":100, "desc":"Sep 11" },
   { "id":"2020-09-12", "y":0,   "desc":"Sep 12" },
   { "id":"2020-09-13", "y":0,   "desc":"Sep 13" },
   { "id":"2020-09-14", "y":20,  "desc":"Sep 14" }
];
```

jsfiddle -->>>>
https://jsfiddle.net/0qkvy91L/

Comment: Do you want to keep the `desc` property?

Comment: Hi yes I want to keep desc property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `find` to find the element in `JsonB` which has the same id with the iterated element of `JsonA` and return the overriden value

```
JsonA = JsonA.map(itemA => {
  const itemB = JsonB.find(itemB => itemB.id === itemA.id)
  return {
    ...itemA,
    ...itemB
  }
```

```js
let JsonA = [
  {
    id: '2020-09-08',
    y: 0,
    desc: 'Sep 08'
  },
  {
    id: '2020-09-09',
    y: 0,
    desc: 'Sep 09'
  },
  {
    id: '2020-09-10',
    y: 0,
    desc: 'Sep 10'
  },
  {
    id: '2020-09-11',
    y: 0,
    desc: 'Sep 11'
  },
  {
    id: '2020-09-12',
    y: 0,
    desc: 'Sep 12'
  },
  {
    id: '2020-09-13',
    y: 0,
    desc: 'Sep 13'
  },
  {
    id: '2020-09-14',
    y: 0,
    desc: 'Sep 14'
  }
]

let JsonB = [
  {
    id: '2020-09-11',
    y: 100
  },

  {
    id: '2020-09-14',
    y: 20
  }
]

JsonA = JsonA.map(itemA => {
  const itemB = JsonB.find(itemB => itemB.id === itemA.id)
  return {
    ...itemA,
    ...itemB
  }
})

console.log('Modified Array', JsonA)
```

Comment: The part to note here that in the original code, it's trying to lookup `JsonB.id` but that's on an element but the entire object. In this answer, it finds the specific element from `JsonB` by matching the `id`.

Answer (score 1):

Your method would make sense if you could be certain that each entry in `JsonA` and each entry in `JsonB` have matching IDs at the same array positions. As this is not the case, you need to search `JsonB` to find each ID from `JsonA`.

Give this a try:

```js
var JsonA = [
   {
      "id":"2020-09-08",
      "y":0,
      "desc":"Sep 08"
   },
   {
      "id":"2020-09-09",
      "y":0,
      "desc":"Sep 09"
   },
   {
      "id":"2020-09-10",
      "y":0,
      "desc":"Sep 10"
   },
   {
      "id":"2020-09-11",
      "y":0,
      "desc":"Sep 11"
   },
   {
      "id":"2020-09-12",
      "y":0,
      "desc":"Sep 12"
   },
   {
      "id":"2020-09-13",
      "y":0,
      "desc":"Sep 13"
   },
   {
      "id":"2020-09-14",
      "y":0,
      "desc":"Sep 14"
   }
]


var JsonB= [
   {
      "id":"2020-09-11",
      "y":100
   },
   
   {
      "id":"2020-09-14",
      "y":20
   }
]



JsonA.map(itemA => {
    const itemBMatch = JsonB.filter(itemB => itemA.id === itemB.id);
        
    if(itemBMatch.length !== 0) {
        itemA.y = itemBMatch[0].y;
    };
});

console.log("Modified Array", JsonA);
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm glad you were able to find a solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple to understand optimal solution that runs in `O(n+m)` time. You should use this if your array sizes are large. The other answer(s) posted here run in `O(n*m)` runtime complexity. Where `n` and `m` are the sizes of arrays `JsonA` and `JsonB`.

```js
var JsonA = [
   { "id":"2020-09-08", "y":0, "desc":"Sep 08" },
   { "id":"2020-09-09", "y":0, "desc":"Sep 09" },
   { "id":"2020-09-10", "y":0, "desc":"Sep 10" },
   { "id":"2020-09-11", "y":0, "desc":"Sep 11" },
   { "id":"2020-09-12", "y":0, "desc":"Sep 12" },
   { "id":"2020-09-13", "y":0, "desc":"Sep 13" },
   { "id":"2020-09-14", "y":0, "desc":"Sep 14" }
];

var JsonB= [
    {"id":"2020-09-11", "y":100 },
    {"id":"2020-09-14", "y":20  }
];

let obj = Object.fromEntries(JsonA.map(e => [e.id, e]));

JsonB.forEach(e => {
   obj[e.id] = obj[e.id] || {};
   Object.assign(obj[e.id], e); 
});

JsonA = Object.values(obj);

console.log(JsonA);
```

Comment: Nice. Would you describe the accepted answer as O(N^2)?

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to replace `item.y` jsonB.y but you need to iterate jsonB also to get the correct id and then replace the value, see below code

```
    JsonA.map(item => {
      console.log("id : "+item.id);
      JsonB.map(newItem => {
            if(item.id == newItem.id) { 
             (item.y = newItem.y);
            }
      }); 
      console.log("##" + item.y);
   });
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tfq82mgw/1/)